# How to Install Network Printer with dynamic IP?

Tags: printer

"We can install network printer by its NAME and with dynamic IP but how it works?"

I would like to know the steps to install the network printer by its name with dynamic IP.

Answer (score 1):

A printer should have a static IP. It does not matter whether you set the IP on the printer itself, or reserve one for it on your DHCP server/router. If it has a dynamic IP, there is a risk that the DHCP server will eventually give it a different address, in which case you will no longer be able to print.

When setting a static IP, make sure it is outside the DHCP range so the DHCP server will never allocate it to some other device.

Once you have set a static address, in Windows you can connect to it by creating a Standard TCP/IP port for it. When installing the driver for the printer, when asked for the port, creta a new TCP/IP port with the printer's IP address. On a Mac, install the printer as a TCP/IP printer.